# NAT Instance maintenance

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-vpc

I have a Django app deployed on AWS Lambda through Zappa and my app needs to communicate with the public internet, so I need to use a NAT Instance. I am using a NAT instance because it's about 10x cheaper than a NAT Gateway using the free tier. The downside is that unlike NAT Gateway, a NAT Instance needs actual maintenance, and I am unsure what type of maintenance it needs. I want to learn about things I need to do to keep my server running well and healthy.

What are things I can do to make sure of that?

Here is my AWS Architecture:

All of the following is in my VPC. I have 1 subnet in ca-central-1a and 1 in ca-central-1b. In the route table, both subnets point to my NAT Instance. I have a 3rd subnet in ca-central-1b and in the route table it points to an internet gateway. My NAT Instance is in ca-central-1b.

My NAT Instance security group NATSG has HTTP and HTTPS inbounds from both of my subnets in ca-central-1a and ca-central-1b and outbound to 0.0.0.0/0. **Should I make another NAT Instance in ca-central-1a and make it only inbound from the subnet in ca-central-1a i.e 1 NAT Instance for each subnet? Would that be healthier/safer?**

Extra information:

**I disabled Source/dest check. Was that a good idea?**

For my AMI I chose a recent community AMI amzn-ami-vpc-nat and I created an Auto Scale Group which has my NAT instance. It only has 1 instance, **is there any point of the Auto Scale Group if there's only 1 instance in it?** I am not sure that I am using the Auto Scale Group right, I simply created it but haven't configured anything.

Comment: The Auto Scaling group sounds like a great way to ensure availability. However, you should test it to confirm what else is required to make it work (eg updating of Route Tables). You do need to disable Source/Dest Check otherwise the NAT process won't work.

Comment: How do I test that Auto Scaling would work? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Terminate an instance. Auto Scaling will replace it. Confirm that it can still operate as a NAT. I suspect it won't, because the Route Table will be pointing at the instance that was terminated. You'd need to do some fancy Lambda stuff to re-point the Route Table to the new instance. A NAT Gateway, on the other hand, is automatically redundant.

Comment: How about creating 2 Nat instances, have them both in the Auto Scaling group and have the Route table configured for both?

Comment: It gets messy: [High Availability for Amazon VPC NAT Instances: An Example - AWS Articles](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/high-availability-for-amazon-vpc-nat-instances-an-example/) Of course, it is all solved by using a NAT Gateway. High Availability is always a trade-off with expense. If your goal is to be low-cost, then you'll need to accept a possibility of lower availability.

Comment: I understand. Thank you John!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Maintenance for NAT instances is necessary for security updates, security groups and instance failures.
- It's not necessary to place NAT instance in every subnet. You can connect  multiple instance through single NAT instance. Also it is recommended to place NAT instance in public subnet.
- source/destination check is enabled by default for each EC2 instance which shows that instance must be the source or destination of  traffic which it send or receive. So source/destination check must be disabled for NAT instance as NAT instance is not source or destination to send or receive the traffic. It
  just act as intermediate to send traffic to the private instances.

  Below link gives the detailed description of Disabling Source/Destination Checks

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck

- Setting up desired capacity to 1 will always keep your 1 NAT instance
  up. But concern is when a NAT instance gets terminated, auto-scaling
  group will launch the respective NAT instance which has
  Source/destination 'enable' by default. We have to make it disable
  manually, Also the entries which where made in route table by
  selecting target as nat-instance-id will not get change and  Route
  Table will be pointing at the instance that was terminated. To get 
  SourceDestCheck attribute disabled for newly launch NAT instance you
  could launch this from the User Data of the instance.
  Here is an example shell script.

> ```
> EC2_INSTANCE_ID=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
> EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
> EC2_REGION=`echo \$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\ | sed -r 's/.{2}$//'`
> echo "Region:" $EC2_REGION
>
> aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $EC2_INSTANCE_ID --source-dest-check "{\"Value\": false}" --region $EC2_REGION
>
> rc=$?; if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then echo "Failure:" $rc; exit $rc; fi
>
> echo "Success"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!! Although I could not figure out how to add the script from the User Data of the instance. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Rony Azrak At the time of instance launch when you go through Configure Instance you have the Advanced Details option at the bottom, here you need to paste the script as the text or as a file. We would suggest you to please refer the updated script, though the initial script was also working fine the updated script will make your task easier. We have checked it at our end and is working fine.

Comment: Much appreciated!! Although is there a way to Configure Instance after having launched the instance? Or do I have to create a new one? I could not find the option to configure it after having already launched it. What about the Auto Scaling Group? Is it useful at all? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, @Rony Azrak for the delayed response. As your concern is to configure instance details after launch, we assume that you are considering about updating user-data script, the possible way to do so is to run the script through a shell. 
Just need to save the given script in .sh file say some a.sh and execute it through command as
 `#sh a.sh`.

But this changes will only be specific to instance, it will not reflect for next upcoming instance which may get launch through autoscaling if you are using it. 
For this purpose, you need to create a new launch configuration with required modification by adding the script in Advanced Details section, as existing launch configuration can't be edited. This ultimately leads to launching a new instance.

About Auto scaling, we would suggest you use auto scaling which will automate your task of launching an instance. It does not incur any extra charge you pay only for resources what you use.